# What kind of specification is required for NodeType.Certificates?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

When attempting to install a cluster, I am getting this error:

```
Cluster manifest validation failed with exception System.ArgumentException: NodeType.Certificates is req
uired if section Security parameter ServerAuthCredentialType is  set to X509
```

I am attempting to install this configuration:

```
.\CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1 -ClusterConfigFilePath .\ClusterConfig.X509.DevCluster.json
```

Getting the following error:

> Running Best Practices Analyzer... Best Practices Analyzer completed
>   successfully. Creating Service Fabric Cluster... Processing and
>   validating cluster config. Configuring nodes. Default installation
>   directory chosen based on system drive of machine 'localhost'. Copying
>   installer to all machines. Configuring machine 'localhost'.
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ClusterManifestValidationException:
>   Cluster manifest validation failed with exception
>   System.ArgumentException: NodeType.Certificates is req uired if
>   section Security parameter ServerAuthCredentialType is  set to X509
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyCertificates(String[]
>   source, String[] destination, ClusterManifestTypeNodeType nodeT ype)
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyDependencies()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.ValidateSettings()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricValidator.Validate()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigureOperation.OnExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, ClusterManifestType clusterManifest, Infrastructure
>   infrastruct ure)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperationPrivate(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, Boolean disableFileTrace)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.NewNodeConfigurationInner(String
>   clusterManifestPath, String infrastructureManifestPath, String
>   jsonClusterConfi gPath, String fabricDataRoot, String fabricLogRoot,
>   String fabricHostCredentialUser, SecureString
>   fabricHostCredentialPassword, Boolean runFabricHostServiceAsManual,
>   Boo lean removeExistingConfiguration, FabricPackageType
>   fabricPackageType, String fabricPackageRoot, String machineName,
>   String bootstrapPackagePath)
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ClusterManifestValidationException:
>   Cluster manifest validation failed with exception
>   System.ArgumentException: NodeType.Certificates is req uired if
>   section Security parameter ServerAuthCredentialType is  set to X509
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyCertificates(String[]
>   source, String[] destination, ClusterManifestTypeNodeType nodeT ype)
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyDependencies()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.ValidateSettings()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricValidator.Validate()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigureOperation.OnExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, ClusterManifestType clusterManifest, Infrastructure
>   infrastruct ure)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperationPrivate(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, Boolean disableFileTrace)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.NewNodeConfigurationInner(String
>   clusterManifestPath, String infrastructureManifestPath, String
>   jsonClusterConfi gPath, String fabricDataRoot, String fabricLogRoot,
>   String fabricHostCredentialUser, SecureString
>   fabricHostCredentialPassword, Boolean runFabricHostServiceAsManual,
>   Boo lean removeExistingConfiguration, FabricPackageType
>   fabricPackageType, String fabricPackageRoot, String machineName,
>   String bootstrapPackagePath)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.NewNodeConfiguration(String
>   clusterManifestPath, String infrastructureManifestPath, String
>   jsonClusterConfigPath , String fabricDataRoot, String fabricLogRoot,
>   String fabricHostCredentialUser, SecureString
>   fabricHostCredentialPassword, Boolean runFabricHostServiceAsManual,
>   Boolean  removeExistingConfiguration, FabricPackageType
>   fabricPackageType, String fabricPackageRoot, String machineName,
>   String bootstrapPackagePath) CreateCluster Error:
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ClusterManifestValidationException:
>   Cluster manifest valid ation failed with exception
>   System.ArgumentException: NodeType.Certificates is required if section
>   Security parameter ServerAuthCredentialType is  set to X509    at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyCertificates(String[]
>   source, String[] destination, ClusterManifestTypeNodeType nodeT ype)
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyDependencies()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.ValidateSettings()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricValidator.Validate()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigureOperation.OnExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, ClusterManifestType clusterManifest, Infrastructure
>   infrastruct ure)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperationPrivate(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, Boolean disableFileTrace)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.NewNodeConfigurationInner(String
>   clusterManifestPath, String infrastructureManifestPath, String
>   jsonClusterConfi gPath, String fabricDataRoot, String fabricLogRoot,
>   String fabricHostCredentialUser, SecureString
>   fabricHostCredentialPassword, Boolean runFabricHostServiceAsManual,
>   Boo lean removeExistingConfiguration, FabricPackageType
>   fabricPackageType, String fabricPackageRoot, String machineName,
>   String bootstrapPackagePath)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.NewNodeConfiguration(String
>   clusterManifestPath, String infrastructureManifestPath, String
>   jsonClusterConfigPath , String fabricDataRoot, String fabricLogRoot,
>   String fabricHostCredentialUser, SecureString
>   fabricHostCredentialPassword, Boolean runFabricHostServiceAsManual,
>   Boolean  removeExistingConfiguration, FabricPackageType
>   fabricPackageType, String fabricPackageRoot, String machineName,
>   String bootstrapPackagePath)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(String
>   machineName)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object
>   )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWithState, F unc`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action` 3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Action`1 body)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__1.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ClusterManifestValidationException:
>   Cluster manifest validation failed with exception
>   System.ArgumentException: No deType.Certificates is required if
>   section Security parameter ServerAuthCredentialType is  set to X509
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyCertificates(String[]
>   source, String[] destination, ClusterManifestTypeNodeType nodeT ype)
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.VerifyDependencies()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.ValidateSettings()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricValidator.Validate()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigureOperation.OnExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, ClusterManifestType clusterManifest, Infrastructure
>   infrastruct ure)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperationPrivate(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters
>   parameters, Boolean disableFileTrace)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.NewNodeConfigurationInner(String
>   clusterManifestPath, String infrastructureManifestPath, String
>   jsonClusterConfi gPath, String fabricDataRoot, String fabricLogRoot,
>   String fabricHostCredentialUser, SecureString
>   fabricHostCredentialPassword, Boolean runFabricHostServiceAsManual,
>   Boo lean removeExistingConfiguration, FabricPackageType
>   fabricPackageType, String fabricPackageRoot, String machineName,
>   String bootstrapPackagePath)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigurationDeployer.NewNodeConfiguration(String
>   clusterManifestPath, String infrastructureManifestPath, String
>   jsonClusterConfigPath , String fabricDataRoot, String fabricLogRoot,
>   String fabricHostCredentialUser, SecureString
>   fabricHostCredentialPassword, Boolean runFabricHostServiceAsManual,
>   Boolean  removeExistingConfiguration, FabricPackageType
>   fabricPackageType, String fabricPackageRoot, String machineName,
>   String bootstrapPackagePath)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(String
>   machineName)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object
>   )<---
>
> Trace folder already exists. Traces will be written to existing trace
>   folder: C:\ooo360\5.7.220\DeploymentTraces Cleaning up faulted
>   installation. FabricRoot not found in registry of target machine
>   localhost. Create Cluster failed. For more information please look at
>   traces in FabricLogRoot. Create Cluster failed with exception:
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManager.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.NewCluster(String
>   clusterConfigurationFilePath, String fabricPackageSourcePath, Boolean
>   noCleanupOnFailure, Bo olean force)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManager.d__2.MoveNext()<---
>
> Create Cluster failed with exception: System.AggregateException: One
>   or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more
>   errors occurred.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManager.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.NewCluster(String
>   clusterConfigurationFilePath, String fabricPackageSourcePath, Boolean
>   noCleanupOnFailure, Boo lean force)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManagerInternal.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.DeploymentManager.d__2.MoveNext()<---

Here's my configuration file:

```
{
"name": "SampleCluster",
"clusterConfigurationVersion": "1.0.0",
"apiVersion": "04-2017",
"nodes": [
    {
        "nodeName": "vm0",
        "iPAddress": "localhost",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r0",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD0"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm1",
        "iPAddress": "localhost",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType1",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r1",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD1"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm2",
        "iPAddress": "localhost",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType2",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r2",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD2"
    }
],
"properties": {
    "diagnosticsStore": 
    {
        "metadata":  "Please replace the diagnostics file share with an actual file share accessible from all cluster machines.",
        "dataDeletionAgeInDays": "7",
        "storeType": "FileShare",
        "connectionstring": "c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\DiagnosticsStore"
    },
    "security": {
        "metadata": "The Credential type X509 indicates this is cluster is secured using X509 Certificates. The thumbprint format is - d5 ec 42 3b 79 cb e5 07 fd 83 59 3c 56 b9 d5 31 24 25 42 64.",
       "ClusterCredentialType": "X509",
       "ServerCredentialType": "X509",
       "CertificateInformation": {
           "ClusterCertificateCommonNames": {
             "CommonNames": [
               {
                 "CertificateCommonName": "ooo-WS-Ashort.ccc.int"
               }
             ],
             "X509StoreName": "My"
           },
            "ServerCertificate": {
                "Thumbprint": "719ECFD3F5xxxxxxxxx21C69CC36514126",
                "X509StoreName": "My"
            },
           "ServerCertificateCommonNames": {
             "CommonNames": [
               {
                 "CertificateCommonName": "ooo-WS-Ashort.ccc.int"
               }
             ],
             "X509StoreName": "My"
           },
           "ClientCertificateThumbprints": [{
               "CertificateThumbprint": "719ECFD3F55xxxxxxx69CC36514126",
               "IsAdmin": false
           }, {
               "CertificateThumbprint": "39C52B527B6xxxxxxxxxxDD115274CBE9A",
               "IsAdmin": true
           }]
        }
    },
    "nodeTypes": [
        {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20001",
                "endPort": "20031"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
        },
        {
            "name": "NodeType1",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19004",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19005",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19006",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19007",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19082",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19083",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20288",
                "endPort": "20318"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
        },
        {
            "name": "NodeType2",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19008",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19009",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19010",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19011",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19084",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19085",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20575",
                "endPort": "20605"
            },
            "isPrimary": false
        }
    ],
    "fabricSettings": [
        {
            "name": "Setup",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "FabricDataRoot",
                    "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FabricLogRoot",
                    "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF\\Log"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

**What am I doing wrong? How do I specify the NodeTypes.Certificates value?**

Comment: Perhaps your thumbprints have that extra character at thw end (assuming you copied them from mmc) could also try with this schema, it's a month newer - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-standalone-cluster-configuration/blob/master/Samples/ClusterConfig.X509.DevCluster.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I bet your clusterManifest.xml is missing Certificates property within NodeTypes definition. Since this file gets generated automatically, did you alter manifest manually? If so, you need to get Certificates section back with all the required certificates(Cluster, Server, Client).
- Next, you should verify the certificates you have in the config are properly installed, and you have correct thumbprints(do not forget about a special hidden character at the beginning of the thumbprint).
- Finally, your SF installation might be corrupted or something, so you could reinstall all the SF artifacts.